# display only centre part of image and on click show full image

Tags: android, listview, picasso

how can i display only `center portion of image` and on click want to display full image in new activity. I'm using listview with image and text portion. I'm displaying image using `Picasso library`.

Here i'm adding code for click event of imageview

I'm generating imageview as per data size because i had create slider type so.

```
Picasso.with(Global.mcontext).load(Utils.URL + data.get(position).Image.get(i).Image).fit().error(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(holder.img_playlist[i]);

holder.img_playlist = new ImageView[data.size()];

    holder.layout_playlist_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (data.get(position).Image != null && data.get(position).Image.size() > 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowImageSecondary.class);
                        Global.Data = data.get(position);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
```

can anyone help me

Comment: you can use center crop as a scale type

Comment: vaibhav kumar where to set center crop in Picasso or in new imageview

Comment: in new imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating your ImageView in your ListView item,Use this code:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

---

And then there is no need to call `fit` or `centerCrop` while setting image using Picasso.

---

Use `centerCrop()` for the imageView and it is available as a Picasso function.

Comment: Center crop requires calling resize with positive width and height

Comment: sorry but I didn't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sac what you want to understand please tell me!

Comment: i already define in my question that imageview is generate every time it is not static it is dynamic

Comment: it works well but image not display properly do you have any more suggestions means image is zoomed now

Comment: This answers your question of showing center portion of image. If you want more customization, you would need to tell the exact expected behavior.

Comment: i had put code to crop image also if user crop image it not display proper but it not crop then it display perfectly

Comment: Could you please post the screenshots of expected behaviour and current behaviour?

Comment: @rkandroid Then you would need to explain it clearly or you can ask in a new question. For now you can mark this answer accepted.